# Add a new category to the navigation bar of the windows files explorer

Tags: vb.net, windows, explorer, windows-shell, windows-explorer

How can I programmatically add a new category to the navigation bar of the windows files explorer. I mean something like this (For Example)

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934839/i-want-to-add-folder-link-in-the-exporer-left-side-panel/31957124#31957124

Answer (score 1):

It is namespace shell extension. NSE must be registered in Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\Namespace\NSE_CLSID. Also it must implement IPropertyStoreFactory and must return True when system requests value of PKEY_IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree property.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934839/i-want-to-add-folder-link-in-the-exporer-left-side-panel/31957124#31957124